# Java regex to find multiple patterns and need to convert it to Map

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a Map from a multi-line `String` with various patterns.
For example, considering the following `String`:

```
:20:94001142322029214336
:86:/PG/1L
:25|11298666
:28::20/1
```

My patterns are like:

```
starting  : OR :: OR | OR || and ending with : OR :: OR | OR ||
```

I am trying to create a map as follows:

```
Key    Value

20    94001142322029214336<br>
86    /PG/1L<br>
25    11298666<br>
28    20/1<br>
```

Could you please help me to create the Java regex or any other solution that can help me to create this map?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any existing code that is erring out?  Writing code from scratch goes a bit and beyond the appropriate scope of a Stack Overflow.  It is easier (and often more helpful) to identify where a specific error in your code is than asking single questions that are only helpful to the specific case of the OP (that few if any will find helpful in the future).

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(:(.*?):|::|\||)", Pattern.DOTALL);
String[] split = ":20:94001142322029214336
:86:/PG/1L
:25|11298666
:28::20/1".split(pattern.pattern());

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression:

```
:(\w+)[:\|]+(.*)
```

**Code**:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile(":(\\w+)[:\\|]+(.*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String input = ":20:94001142322029214336\n:86:/PG/1L\n:25|11298666\n:28::20/1";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("Key=\"%s\", Value=\"%s\"%n", 
                entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Key="20", Value="94001142322029214336"
Key="86", Value="/PG/1L"
Key="25", Value="11298666"
Key="28", Value="20/1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the string pattern \\d+ assumes u have a digits only but in my case it can be alphanumeric. So my key and value both can be alphanumeric..what should be the regex in that case. One thing i frogot to mention is starting character can be multiple as well like : :: |

Comment: One more problem is if the value comes in as multi line then this regex won't work for examples :20:94001142322029214336\n123456\n345678:86:/PG/1L\n:25|11298666\n:28::20/1 so key 20 and value should be 94001142322029214336\n123456\n345678, with above regex it gives me value as 94001142322029214336 any quick tips...

Comment: Use the regex: `:(\w+)[|:]([^:]+)`, ie: `":(\\w+)[|:]([^:]+)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String strArray[] = { ":20:94001142322029214336",
                 ":86:/PG/1L" ,
                 ":25||11298666" ,
                 ":28::20/1"
               };
HashMap<String,String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
for(String str11 : strArray){
    String subStr[] = str11.replaceFirst(":","").split(":{2}|:|\\|{2}|\\|");
    map.put(subStr[0],subStr[1]);
    System.out.println(subStr[0]+"-->"+subStr[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
20-->94001142322029214336
86-->/PG/1L
25-->11298666
28-->20/1
```

Regex `:{2}|:|\\|{2}|\\|` Explanation :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String s = ":20:94001142322029214336\n:86:/PG/1L\n:25|11298666\n:28::20/1";
    System.out.println("Original string: \n"+s);

    // Transform the string into an array of lines
    String[] lines = s.split("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // Split using regex - notice that the two-character symbols need to go first
        String[] parts = lines[i].split("::|:|\\|\\||\\|");
        map.put(parts[1], parts[2]);
    }

    System.out.println("\nMap: ");
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key+"->"+map.get(key));
    }
}
```